# Can't understand error about Object array

Tags: java

TestAddress.java

```
Address[] adrsarr = new Address[5];
        adrsarr[0] = new Address("B402", "3", "42", "Behind Sector 9",
                "New Delhi", "Delhi", "Delhi", "India", "232113");
        adrsarr[1] = new Address("B1", "2", "61", "Bb Road 2", "Mumbai",
                "Mumbai", "Maharashtra", "India", "1213");
        adrsarr[2] = new Address("AH2", "325", "98", "BPGC", "Goa", "Goa",
                "Goa", "India", "403726");
        adrsarr[3] = new Address("a222", "2", "81", "Sector market",
                "New Delhi", "Delhi", "Delhi", "India", "11a001");
```

Address.java has a constructor of type `Address()` and of `Address(string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string)`

Now this given code does not work inside the main TestAddress class, it gives an error on the line where I'm declaring adrsarr

```
- Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token
```

But if I put it inside a function like buildArr(), then it compiles flawlessly, no errors.

Any idea what's happening? How am I supposed to initialize an object array without making a function?

Comment: Please post the whole code as you probally forgot a bracket above the code you posted.

Comment: Heh, I didn't I've already checked for that.

Comment: Still helps to post the complete code

Comment: The code is correct so there must be some other reason for getting the error, maybe it's better to post the complete `TestAddress` class code.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR is right, maybe you put your initialization code outside any method and this is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

> Now this given code does not work inside the main TestAddress class,
>   it gives an error on the line where I'm declaring adrsarr

you can't **populate your array** outside a **method,constructor or an initialization block**.

```
 public class Country {
    Address[] add = new Address[3];
    add[0] = new Address();// this would not **compile**, put it inside a constructor /method.

      {
           this.add[0] = new  Address();// populating inside an init block, works fine 
       }
      public country() {
        this.add[0] = new  Address(); //populating inside a constructor, works fine
       }
       public void method(){
         this.add[0] = new Address();//populating inside a method, works fine
        }
  }
```

Comment: In fact the array is populated in the `TestAddres` class main method.

Comment: @remigio read it propery, i think he meant a class (main TestAddress class), not the main method of the class, but logically speaking, you can populate it inside main.

Comment: I've read it carefully, but @user1265125 speaks about using an array of `Address` in the `main` function of the `TestAddress` class, so the comment is not appropriate.

Comment: @remigio well, you could be right, but he dint mention main function in the question . (inside the main TestAddress class).

Comment: You're right, I interpreted `Now this given code does not work inside the main TestAddress class` as `Now this given code does not work inside the main method of the TestAddress class`. Maybe @user1265125 put that code outside any method. I apologize for voting down, I'm just voting up your answer.

Comment: Definitely yes, but I'm not allowed to vote up your answer unless you edit it.

Answer (score -1):

Use an Array Initializer instead the initializing assignment statements.

```
Address[] add = { new Address(), new Adress(), new Adress() };
```

Array Initializers can only be used in a declaration or as part of an Array creation Expression (see [Java Language Specification - Chapter 10.6 "Array Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6))

Comment: Initializers are not the only way to initialize arrays, you can populate them assigning elements in a subsequent assignment after you have declared them.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I did not say that initializers are the only way. I said that initializers can only be used in a declaration or... The way you mentioned is described in the answer above.